# Schedule task for one year from now

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks

What is the best way to schedule an event for a month or a year from now?
For example, I want my program to send a notification one year after a customer's registration.

I try to use celery with redis using the eta option but, at some point, the task multiplies and sends the same notification to the same customer (like 600 times). I also think that using a cronjob is not the best option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you store the date that the customer account is created then you could just have a script run every day that queries the records of customers where createDate is one year in the past from today. You then send the anniversary message to all of those customers

Comment: Thanks @BigGerman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to push something in the queue that you are not going to read for 1 year.

Store registration date in the database. Write a program that reads the database and pushes information to a topic. You can run this program everyday and it will find all the people who should be notified.

Comment: Thanks @JR ibkr, I thought that running a script every day is completely unnecessary but it seems to be a consensual idea. I'll do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

As JR ibkr pointed, it may not be a good idea to schedule a task to 1 year from now, but run a daily task to scan for people to notify.

But regardless, what you are seeing may be related to a bug with celery + redis configuration, which is discussed here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4400 .

You may try using RabbitMQ as the message broker to avoid this issue, or try one of the suggestions in that discussion.

Hope you don't need to wait for 1 year to see if it works :)